# javascript how to use index of not with select array

Tags: javascript

I have a value, call it a, and a select box with id = "sid".  I'm in javascript and want to know if my value a is one of the options in the select box.

I got this far:  HTML:

```
<select id = "sid">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
</select>
<script>
  isThere('sid')
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
function isthere(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id).options;

  for (j = 0; j<= 1; j++) {
  alert ("arr is " + x[j].text );
} 

var c = x.text.indexOf("a");
  alert ("c is " + c);
}
```

The loop gives the right answers for x[j].text.  I don't get a value for c.  Firebug gives me the error "x.text is undefined".

What is the right way to use indexOf find out if "a" is in this select box?  And efficiency-wise, would I be better off just looping through x.text[j]?

Comment: Your `c` and `x.text` is not in the loop. Must be `x[j].text` by the way

Comment: `x` is a **`NodeList`**. `NodeList`s don't have a property `text`.

Comment: Actually `x` is an `HTMLOptionsCollection`. But yeah there's no `text` property.

Comment: @Aaronius: I thought the collections extend NodeList, but apparently they don't...

Comment: Didn't know it is a nodelist.  Following up on this clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` if you have an array of values.

To get an array of values, you can use

```
[].map.call(x, function(option) {
    return option.value;
});
```

Therefore, you can use

```
[].map.call(x, function(option) {
    return option.value;
}).indexOf("a");
```

In ECMAScript 6, you can simplify it to

```
[].map.call(x, option => option.value).indexOf("a");
```

```js
var x = document.getElementById("sid");
alert([].map.call(x, function(option) {
  return option.value;
}).indexOf("a"));
```

```html
<select id="sid">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
</select>
```

Comment: indexOf is quite recent on array in Javascript (ecmascript 5) you might have issues with older browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @DavidLaberge: So is `.map()` and `.some()`.

Comment: Hi Oriol, I tried the [].map.call etc. and got an error "x is not defined".  This is after x[0].text and x[1].text show correctly.  I tried changing x to document.getElementById("sid") without the .option, same result.  Also, shouldn't it be option.text?  My browser is Firefox 34.0-- don't think it is old.

Comment: @BettyMock You define `x` inside a function but then you use it outside. Define it outside instead. It doesn't matter much if you use [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-option-value) or [`text`](//www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-option-text), because the [value](//www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-option-value) of an option element is the value of the [`value`](//www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-value) content attribute, if there is one, or, if there is not, the value of the element's [`text`](//www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-option-text) IDL attribute.

Comment: Hey Oriol, I tried again and this time it worked.  Must have had something balled up earlier in the function, because I copied and pasted your code.  In the real program I do have values in the select list, so .text seems like the way to go.  I'm unfamiliar with your syntax, but will look it up and understand it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: any thought about whether this is more or less efficient than just looping through the node?  my test select box is small, but who knows what the eventual users may do.

Comment: @BettyMock ES5 array methods like `map` usually iterate slower than `for` loops. Moreover, `map` creates a new array, which will be iterated again by `indexOf`. So `for` loops are probably faster and require less memory.

Comment: Hi Oriol, if you still have some patience, I went on to the next thing where I need something like y = x[j].toFixed(2); I can't get a value for y because x[j] is a node.  So I tried your map thing, y = [].map.call(x, function(option) {return option.value;}); hoping that would give me an array, but I keep getting that y is undefined. I tried appending the toFix(2) like the indexOf but got an error that it is not a function.  Clearly I don't understand something here.  If the map is really producing an array why can't I pick it up?  Would you help me a bit further?

Comment: @Betty `toFixed` is a method of numbers. Not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Oriol, yes it is a method for numbers.  This is a separate problem from the indexOf matter (once you solved that for me I went on to the next issue).  And you know what -- I didn't need to convert the node.  I used num = parseFloat(x[j]) and num turned out to work with toFix.  So that issue is gone.  However, there is something I still don't understand.  What kind of object is the expression you suggest: .map.call(x, function(option) {    return option.value;})?  And how can I place this object in a variable?  Sorry to be dense.  My javascript skills are elementary.

Comment: [`[].map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array. You can store it in a variable using `var variable = [].map.call(x, callback);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
function isThere(id, value) {
    return Array.prototype.some.call(document.getElementById(id).options, 
        function (i) { return i.value === value });
}
```

Note that I added the `value` param to the function.

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4w28nnLn/) working.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
    function isThere(id, value) {
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById(id).length; ++i){
            if (document.getElementById(id).options[i].value === value){
              return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<HTML>
 <head>
  <script>
   function makeArray(id) {
       var x = document.getElementById(id);
       var arr = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
           arr.push(x.options[i].value);
       }
       return arr;
   }
   function isthere(id) {
    var arr = makeArray(id);
    var c = arr.indexOf("b");
    alert ("c is " + c);
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <BODY onload="isthere('sid');">
  <select id = "sid">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you `x.text.indexOf("a");` are refence to de array `<option>`. no the text of the element.
... you can also ...

var x = document.getElementById(id).options;

```
  for (j = 0; j<= 1; j++) {
   if (x[j].text.indexOf("a"){
       alert("it is a");
   }
}
```

or 
        var x = document.getElementById(id).options;

```
  x.forEach(function (element) {
        if (element.text.indexOf("a")){
            alert("it is a");
        }
  });
```

you can use `==` instead `.indexOf` LIKE that

```
if (element.text == "a")){
            alert("it is a");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display text of selected option you can use this:

```
function isthere(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id).options;
 var c = x[x.selectedIndex].text
 alert ("c is " + c);
 }
```

indexOf is used to find index in array and since x is *[HTMLOptionsCollection](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/html2/HTMLOptionsCollection.html)*
you cannot use indexOf